# How to store active class of a div when page reloads using local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not able to save active class for a div on page reload, when I click button in first div then its active class is removed and next class is made active. But when the page reloads in second div, how to save active class for second div when page is reloaded . i tried using local storage but i dunno that.

```
<div class="divs active" id="first">
  <h1> first div</h1>
   <a class="btn-link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn-first">Next - 2</a>
</div>
<div class="divs" id="second">
 <h1> second div</h1>
  <a class="btn-link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn-second"/>Next -3 </a>
</div>
<div class="divs" id="third">
 <h1> third div</h1>
   <a class="btn-link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn-third"/>Next -1</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#btn-first').click(function(){
    $('.divs').removeClass('active');
    var activeID = $('#second').addClass('active');
    console.log(activeID);
    localStorage.setItem("activeDIV", activeID);

    //var reloadactiveDIV = localStorage.getItem("activeDIV");

    // var activeID = $('#second');
    // localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $activeID );
    // var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    // if (activeTab) {
    //     $('.divs').removeClass('active');
    //     $('#second').addClass('active');
    // }
  });

  $('#btn-second').click(function(){
    $('.divs').removeClass('active');
    $('#third').addClass('active');
  });
  $('#btn-third').click(function(){
    $('.divs').removeClass('active');
    $('#first').addClass('active');
  });


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can store the `index` of the active div in local storage, instead of the entire jQuery object, and then re-set the `active` class on the element within the index of localStorage when the page is next loaded.

Also note that you can DRY up the logic by using a single event handler for all the buttons. You can find the parent `.divs` and retrieve the next one, looping back to the first if there is no next sibling. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // set active on click:
  $('.btn-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $parentDiv = $(this).closest('div');
    var $nextDiv = $parentDiv.next('div');
    var $divs = $('.divs').removeClass('active');

    if (!$nextDiv.length) 
        $nextDiv = $divs.first();    

    $nextDiv.addClass('active');
    localStorage.setItem("activeDiv", $nextDiv.index('.divs'));
  });

  // set active on load:
  var activeIndex = localStorage.getItem("activeDiv");
  if (activeIndex)
    $('.divs').removeClass('active').eq(activeIndex).addClass('active')
});
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf6smofv/)

Note that I couldn't place a working example in a SO Snippet as it has restrictions in place on accessing localStorage.

Comment: i prefer using sessionStorage instead of localStorage. Session Storage property maintains a separate storage area for each given origin that's available for the duration of the page session i.e as long as the browser is open, including page reloads and restores. Local Storage does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and reopened.

Comment: You're right, although I don't see it as a matter of preference. It all about how long you need the data to be stored for